# how to add db directory to web.xml

Tags: apache, tomcat, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I have a java web app configured with apache v9.0 and eclipse IDE. What I need is to keep my database in `C:\db` so It cannot be access directly from outside and should be away from my webapp project directory. What I don't is how to let my web app know that if a user request for a file it should go and check it in my `C:\db` and reply back with the file.

Based in my research, some was saying to specify my directory in my webapp web.xml file and others was saying I need to specify it in my tomcat/conf/server.xml file.

I'd really appreciate if somebody tell me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your database path `C:\db` as `JVM argument` and accessing it in application. you may try this as two ways either set as system property and access when it required or set as JVM argument and access it.

1. **SetSystemProperties**
   `System.setProperty("database", "C:\\db");
   .
   .
   access it as and when required
       String databasepath= System.getProperty("database");`
2. **Setting as JVM Arguments.**

   1. Double Click on your tomcat server on which your web application is present.
   2. Click on "Open launch configuration" link and go to Arguments Tab.
   3. in vmArguments apend the entry like below.
      `-Ddatabase="C:\db"`
   4. A `-D` is placed in front of each system property that we are passing in as a VM argument, and following this is an `equal sign` followed by the value of that `system property`.
   5. And access it in your project where its required like below.
      `String databasepath= System.getProperty("database");`